# Android - Is this a java coded application or or a Webview?

Tags: android, webview

hello there is an applicaton on play store. I want to know is this a java coded application or an application having a webview inside it?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.gaziantepkentrehberi

Comment: Ask the developer of the app. Or use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the UI we would not be able to say 100% if it is web based or native application.

But from my experience, i think it is a Native/Hybrid application but not an app with only WebView components in it.

I did not download or install the app.